# How to avoid hiding div background when scrolling horizontally

Tags: html, scroll, background-color

Anybody's got ideas, how to get around the problem that scrolling horizontally clears  div background colors/images.

There's a similar problem example for example on www.f-i.com.

If the browser window is small enough to display horizontal scolling and then you scroll to right the content gets hidden (probably the background color of the divs get replaced by body background color... or something)

This happens at least with current versions of Mac Chrome and Safari.
I'm using 960.gs if it has anything to do with that..

Thanks in advance,

Harry S

Answer (score 1):

On the www.f-i.com site, if you look carefully the div.main has overflow: hidden;

If you remove this it all works fine.

Comment: I'm having this problem but there are no  `overflow: hidden` properties anywhere in the css document. Do you have any other ideas about why this happens?

Comment: @deps_stats I will have to take a look over the website. I can't think of a general rule why this would happen.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I figured out that I was missing `min-width` with the appropriate width of the page.